# Whis is the Default Spinner Typeface

Tags: android, android-spinner, typeface

Does anyone know which is the default typeface font of Spinner in Android. I want to set an edittext with the same font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default typeface of any widget is `Droid-Sans`, if you want that font you shouldn't have to do anything.